# Read microsoft office files with out Office installed for a site hosted on GoDadday

Tags: c#, ms-word

Is it possible to read and open files through c# without MS Office installed. I have a site hosted in godaddy that particular code which reads word Works locally but not in live site. This is the m,ethod that im using to read the content of the uploaded file (both doc or docx) but its not working in GoDaddy

```
public static string ReadResume(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                string contentOfResume = string.Empty;
                Application application = new Application();
                Document doc = application.Documents.Open(path, Type.Missing, true);
                application.Selection.WholeStory();
                application.Selection.Copy();
                contentOfResume = application.Selection.Range.Text;
                application.Quit(false, false, false);
                return contentOfResume;
            }
        }
```

I have tried

> NetOffice

But it didnt worked as i noticed that internally it uses word interop and they mentioned it is not a replacement.

So I would like to know if there are any Free C# Libraries available.

Comment: Which version of MS Office files? If they are docx maybe you can just unzip them and go for the internal xml directly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats

Comment: Both doc and Docx files

Comment: You are not very specific about the scenario. E.g. " that particular code which reads word Works locally but not in live site" doesn't make sense. I understand that you are probably not a native speaker. Try to use short, simple sentences, provide technical information (which usually is pretty language indifferent) and, best, provide code samples. Code is a language which we all understand here.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening. +1 Edited

Comment: Does Open XML requires Office to be installed ?

Comment: I think what you did locally was build an application for MS Office, as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx, first section. Is that right? And I would assume strongly that you need Office installed on the machine running the program (i.e. your godaddy server). But I also think that you could use OpenOffice for that as well, as suggested in my answer, which would be free.

Answer (score 0):

Depends and what you need from the file, you can unzip and parse the XML. I have seen that done before with some success.

This is free but limited to so many pages / paras

http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-component.html

Also, hunt around for WORD -> HTML tools.

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice reads, manipulates and writes MS Office documents and can be automated. Cf. https://www.openoffice.org/udk/common/man/tutorial/office_automation.html.